# XIMA Formcycle problems with images preview

Tags: java, javafx

*I have the following problem* -

I'm trying to install the latest version of **XIMA Formcycle** software, but I'm having problems with Image Preview feature inside the application.

In their support page, it is described that you need JavaFX 11 in order the image previews to be displayed.

The environment I have is built with Server JRE 8.

My question is - how can I install **JavaFX 11** ( from what I understood it is a feature in Java, to run together with Server JRE 8)?

Is JavaFX a part of Server JRE 8?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is no longer packaged with the JDK as of JDK 11. You needed to [install JavaFX separately](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).